# why we should use a template wrapper in the following code?

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T>
void write_me(T t)
{}

template<>
void write_me<const std::string&>(const std::string&)
{}

// Q2> what is the purpose of this template?
template <typename T> struct convert_type_to_ref 
{
    typedef T value_type;
};

template <> 
struct convert_type_to_ref <std::string>
{
    typedef std::string const & value_type;
};

template <> 
struct convert_type_to_ref <std::string &>
{
    typedef std::string const & value_type;
};

template <typename T> struct HelloStruct {
    void operator()(const T& t) const {
        write_me<typename convert_type_to_ref<T>::value_type>(t);
    }
};        

template <typename T> struct TValue
{
    typedef T value_type;
};

template <typename T>
void functionAAA(const T& one_arg)
{
    HelloStruct<typename TValue<T>::value_type>()(one_arg);
    // HelloStruct<T>()(one_arg); // Q1> Why not simply use T?
}
```

I have seen some legacy code similar as above.

Question 1> what is the difference between the following two cases? what is the key benefit to choose case 1?

```
HelloStruct<typename TValue<T>::value_type>()(one_arg); // case 1
```

VS

```
HelloStruct<T>()(one_arg); // Why not simply use T?     // case 2
```

Question 2> why do we have to introduce an indirection here as below?

```
write_me<typename convert_type_to_ref<T>::value_type>(t);
```

Why not directly call as follows?

```
write_me<T>(t);
```

Thank you

Comment: The code you present seems to be just added complication for no advantage. Are  you sure that you're presenting the full definitions of the templates.

Comment: "Q2> what is the purpose of this template?" maybe not even the author knows. Either it is missing a `&` at the right place or the template is completely pointless

Comment: a "better" name would be `convert_type_to_type`

Comment: `convert_type_to_ref ` does not do what it says it should do.  Are yo sure the code is correct and it is not `typedef T& value_type;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver, I have updated my OP with two template specialization for string.

Comment: Looks like someone has a silly way of re-implementing `std::add_reference`

Comment: After digging further on the code, I realized why the original author added all those templates. Basically, he only defined a specialization of `write_me<const std::string&>`. If the input data is of type std::string, the compiler will report errors. With the help of convert_type_to_ref, he can convert the std::string to const std::string&, so the compiler will be happy.

Comment: Refer to http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm. I decided to use a different way to write the new code so that I can replace all those templates with overloaded function write_me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1> what is the difference between the following two cases? what is the key benefit to choose case 1?

`HelloStruct<typename TValue<T>::value_type>()(one_arg);` and `HelloStruct<T>()(one_arg);` are identical.

`TValue` might be used as-is to avoid deduction:

```
template <typename T> void fooA(typename TValue<T>::value_type);
template <typename T> void fooB(T);
```

then `fooA(42)` would be invalid and require explicit `fooA<int>(42)`.

whereas both `fooB(42)` and `fooB<int>(42)` are valid.

> Question 2> why do we have to introduce an indirection here as below?

`convert_type_to_ref<T>` seems to be a tentative to allow to pass parameter *"efficiency"* (as [boost::call_traits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm))

so

```
write_me<typename convert_type_to_ref<std::string>::value_type>(t);
```

is

```
write_me<const std::string&>(t);
```

whereas

```
write_me<typename convert_type_to_ref<int>::value_type>(t);
```

is

```
write_me<int>(t);
```

but in

```
template <typename T> struct HelloStruct {
    void operator()(const T& t) const {
        write_me<typename convert_type_to_ref<T>::value_type>(t);
    }
};
```

`t` is already pass by const reference, so this micro-optimization seems even more superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

For your question 1) the two cases are the same ... in that context. However there is context where it cannot be the same.
This topic is called type traits, using the first writing can allow a more generic way to determine the fundamental type of a more complex data structure.
e.g.

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <type_traits>

    template<class type>
    struct traits
    {
        typedef typename traits<typename type::value_type>::value_type value_type;
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<unsigned char>
    {
        typedef unsigned char value_type;
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<schar>
    {
        typedef schar value_type;
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<unsigned short>
    {
        typedef unsigned short value_type;
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<int>
    {
        typedef int value_type;
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<unsigned>
    {
        typedef unsigned value_type;
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<long>
    {
        typedef long value_type;
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<unsigned long>
    {
        typedef unsigned long value_type;
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<long long>
    {
        typedef long long value_type;
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<float>
    {
        typedef float value_type;
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<double>
    {
        typedef double value_type;
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<long double>
    {
        typedef double value_type;
    };

    int main()
    {

        std::cout<<"CHECK: "<<std::is_same<float, traits<std::vector<std::list<float> > >::value_type>()<<std::endl;
        return 0;
        }
```

In the case 1 calling `HelloStruct<typename traits<T>::value_type>()(one_arg);` if T if a complex structure (e.g. `std::vector<std::list<float> >`) will create a instance of `HelloStruct<float>` while `HelloStruct<T>()(one_arg);` will create an instance of `HelloStruct<std::vector<std::list<float> > >`.

Question 2) the indirection is just an information for the compiler about the scope of the typename to replace.
e.g.

```
typedef float value_type;

struct useless_struct
{
  typedef double value_type;
}; 

HelloStruct<useless_struct::value_type> a; // == HelloStruct<double>
HelloStruct<value_type> b; // == HelloStruct<float>
```

Hope it helps.